# Загрузить бота на сервер

Tags: python, бот

У меня есть бот для телеграмма на python. Хочу загрузить его на сервер, чтобы он работал постоянно. Проблема в том, что в коде есть функция авторизации, которую нужно проходит в ручную(ввод данных из консоли). Как мне сделать так, чтобы после деплоя на сервер у меня был доступ к вводу данных?

Comment: А почему не сделать ввод данных через бота?

Comment: Это бот, который парсит каналы, используя telethon. Нужно пройти одну авторизацию и все. Авторизация через invate код от самого тг

Comment: мой вопрос не изменился ):

Comment: Если вы хотите пушить на сервер подобный heroku то из документации - Интерфейс heroku командной строки (CLI) является неотъемлемой частью использования Heroku